# Flutter How to refresh StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, listener, onchange

Consider the following code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> _createDataStream(){   
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("data").limit.(_myLimit).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
              return Text(_myLimit.toString);   
            }
        );
}
```

I want that the StreamBuilder refreshes when the `_myLimit` Variable changes.
It's possible doing it like this:

```
void _incrementLimit(){
    setState(() =>_myLimit++);
}
```

My Question is if there is another, faster way, except the `setState((){});` one.
Because I don't want to recall the whole `build()` method when the `_myLimit` Variable changes.

I figured out another Way but I feel like there is a even better solution because I think I don't make use of the `.periodic` functionality and I got a nested Stream I'm not sure how usual this is:

```
Stream<int> myStream = Stream.periodic(Duration(), (_) => _myLimit);
...
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
...
return StreamBuilder<int>(
                    stream: myStream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot){
                      return _createDataStream;
                    },
                  ),
...
}
```

---

**Solution(s)**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  int myNum = 0;

  final StreamController _myStreamCtrl = StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream get onVariableChanged => _myStreamCtrl.stream;
  void updateMyUI() => _myStreamCtrl.sink.add(myNum);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _myStreamCtrl.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child:
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: onVariableChanged,
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                  updateMyUI();
                  return Text(". . .");
                }
                return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Increment"),
              onPressed: (){
                myNum++;
                updateMyUI();
                },
        )
        ],
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

Some other ideas, how the StreamBuilder also could look like:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: onVariableChanged,
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
      return Text(myNum.toString());
    }
    return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
  },
),
```

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: onVariableChanged,
  initialData: myNum,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    if(snapshot.data == null){
      return Text("...");
    }
    return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
  },
),
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declare a `StreamController` with `broadcast`, then set a friendly name to the `Stream` of this `StreamController`, then everytime you want to rebuild the wraped widget (the child of the `StreamBuilder` just use the `sink` property of the `StreamController` to `add` a new value that will trigger the `StreamBuilder`.

You can use `StreamBuilder` and `AsyncSnapshot` without setting the type.

But if you use `StreamBuilder<UserModel>` and `AsyncSnapshot<UserModel>` when you type `snapshot.data.` you will see all variables and methods from the `UserModel`.

```
final StreamController<UserModel> _currentUserStreamCtrl = StreamController<UserModel>.broadcast();
Stream<UserModel> get onCurrentUserChanged => _currentUserStreamCtrl.stream;
void updateCurrentUserUI() => _currentUserStreamCtrl.sink.add(_currentUser);

StreamBuilder<UserModel>(
  stream: onCurrentUserChanged,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<UserModel> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data != null) {
      print('build signed screen, logged as: ' + snapshot.data.displayName);
      return blocs.pageView.pagesView; //pageView containing signed page 
    }
    print('build login screen');
    return LoginPage(); 

    //print('loading');
    //return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
)
```

This way you can use a `StatelessWidget` and `refresh just a single sub-widget` (an icon with a different color, for example) `without using setState` (that rebuilds the entire page).

For performance, streams are the best approach.

**Edit:**
I'm using `BLoC architecture` approach, so it's much better to declare the variables in a homePageBloc.dart (that has a normal controller class with all business logic) and create the StreamBuilder in the homePage.dart (that has a class that extends Stateless/Stateful widget and is responsible for the UI).

**Edit:** My `UserModel.dart`, you can use `DocumentSnapshot` instead of `Map<String, dynamic>` if you are using Cloud Firestore database from Firebase.

```
class UserModel {

  /// Document ID of the user on database
  String _firebaseId = ""; 
  String get firebaseId => _firebaseId;
  set firebaseId(newValue) => _firebaseId = newValue;

  DateTime _creationDate = DateTime.now();
  DateTime get creationDate => _creationDate;

  DateTime _lastUpdate = DateTime.now();
  DateTime get lastUpdate => _lastUpdate;

  String _displayName = "";
  String get displayName => _displayName;
  set displayName(newValue) => _displayName = newValue;

  String _username = "";
  String get username => _username;
  set username(newValue) => _username  = newValue;

  String _photoUrl = "";
  String get photoUrl => _photoUrl;
  set photoUrl(newValue) => _photoUrl = newValue;

  String _phoneNumber = "";
  String get phoneNumber => _phoneNumber;
  set phoneNumber(newValue) => _phoneNumber = newValue;

  String _email = "";
  String get email => _email;
  set email(newValue) => _email = newValue;

  String _address = "";
  String get address => _address;
  set address(newValue) => _address = newValue;

  bool _isAdmin = false;
  bool get isAdmin => _isAdmin;
  set isAdmin(newValue) => _isAdmin = newValue;

  /// Used on first login
  UserModel.fromFirstLogin() {
    _creationDate     = DateTime.now();
    _lastUpdate       = DateTime.now();
    _username         = "";
    _address          = "";
    _isAdmin          = false;
  }

  /// Used on any login that isn't the first
  UserModel.fromDocument(Map<String, String> userDoc) {
    _firebaseId           = userDoc['firebaseId']  ?? '';
    _displayName          = userDoc['displayName'] ?? '';
    _photoUrl             = userDoc['photoUrl'] ?? '';
    _phoneNumber          = userDoc['phoneNumber'] ?? '';
    _email                = userDoc['email'] ?? '';
    _address              = userDoc['address'] ?? '';
    _isAdmin              = userDoc['isAdmin'] ?? false;
    _username             = userDoc['username'] ?? '';
    //_lastUpdate           = userDoc['lastUpdate'] != null ? userDoc['lastUpdate'].toDate() : DateTime.now();
    //_creationDate         = userDoc['creationDate'] != null ? userDoc['creationDate'].toDate() : DateTime.now();
  }

  void showOnConsole(String header) { 

    print('''

      $header

      currentUser.firebaseId: $_firebaseId
      currentUser.username: $_username
      currentUser.displayName: $_displayName
      currentUser.phoneNumber: $_phoneNumber
      currentUser.email: $_email
      currentUser.address: $_address
      currentUser.isAdmin: $_isAdmin
      '''
    );
  }

  String toReadableString() {
    return  
      "displayName: $_displayName; "
      "firebaseId: $_firebaseId; "
      "email: $_email; "
      "address: $_address; "
      "photoUrl: $_photoUrl; "
      "phoneNumber: $_phoneNumber; "
      "isAdmin: $_isAdmin; ";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Gustavo, thanks for your Answer! I tried implementing it, but I'm doing something wrong, please look at the EDIT on my Question :)

Comment: I think thats because the connection state waiting is the state of the stream till it closes on dispose. The stream will always be waiting for something to be added on sink. I dont use connection state. Compare if data is null, if is null probably is something being loaded, so render a progressa indicator, if its not you render the data or some other widget

Comment: This does not fix it. Anyways, thank you for your help! I found another solution now, using the ValueListenableBuilder Widget.

Comment: Just found your error:
You don't need to call updateMyUI() on initState, and you HAVE to call every time you want to rebuild the StreamBuilder, in the RaisedButton on the onPressed you have to call updateMyUI() after increasing the number.  
  
Like this:  
onPressed: () { myNum++; updateMyUI(); }

And use snapshot.data != null to show empty text

Comment: Yes this works! But for some reason the Stream will still stuck in his return for data == null or ConnectionState.waiting, the Stream needs to be triggered. When I added the updateMyUI() in the data==null case or ConnectionState.waiting it works and the Stream is displaying the initial value of myNum. If you are checking for data == null there is also another way except calling updateMyUI() to trigger the Stream, you just could use the "initialData" property of the StreamBuilder and fill it with myNum. I will edit my question. Thank you!