# Showing one card in flutter when no other cards are displaying

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a group of cards that are connected to my cloud firestore which shows when the icon related to each card is chosen. However, I want a card that tells the user to choose an icon when none of the other cards are showing. This is my code:

```
class Tips extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('moodIcons').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data... Please Wait');

              var currentCards = 0;

              return Container(
                  child: new ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      if (document.data()['display'] == true) {
                          //code to display each card when specific icon is chosen
                      } else {
                        if (currentCards < 1) {
                          currentCards++;
                          return new Card(
                              child: new Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Container(
                                    width: 400.0,
                                    height: 45.0,
                                    child: new Text(
                                      "Choose an icon to show a tip!",
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ));
```

Currently, the card shows all the time but I want it to disappear when an icon is clicked. When an icon is clicked, the value of `display` becomes true.
I tried to use a counter so that if the value of `display` is true then it adds one to the counter then if the counter is more than 0, the card in the `else` statement wont show. However, this didn't work as I couldn't return the value of the counter from within the `if` statement.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could conditionally add an item at the beginning of your `ListView` if no `document` is set to `display: true`:

```
class Tips extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('moodIcons').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data... Please Wait');
          return Container(
            child: new ListView(children: [
              if (!snapshot.data.documents
                  .any((doc) => doc.data()['display'] == true))
                Card(child: Text("Choose an icon to show a tip!")),
              ...snapshot.data.documents
                  .where((doc) => doc.data()['display'] == true)
                  .map((doc) => MyWidget(doc))
                  .toList(),
            ]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just used ```if (!snapshot.data.documents.any((doc) => doc.data()['display'] == true))``` and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be done by `StatelessWidget` you need some state management like `Bloc` or `Riverpod`, your own etc.
a good  answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60664774/7351586)
You need to abstract your stream and create an event/action when you click on the icon.
That event is to be handlined via the above mentioned approaches. where a new card will be pushed to the stream.

Or you can make your widget `Stateful`, create a list of `Card` Widgets (to provide to your list builder) and use `setState` to add a element to a `Card` to the list.